# Assigning values to a null char *

Tags: c++

In the following code:

```
const char * my_func1(char const *str)
{
    const char *a = func(); // returns a char *, but I guess its ok to assign non-const to const
    if(a == NULL)
    {
        MY_String b = str;      //MY_String is an inhouse class with string functions
        b.replace("\"", "\'");  //replace " with '
        a = (const char *)b;    //MY_string has an operator (const char *)
    } 

    return a;
}
```

The problem I am having is, when `a` is `null`, and it enters the `if` block, the assignment to `a` is not working properly, and I get garbage. Is it because `a` is `null` that I cannot assign a value to it? How do I fix this?

Comment: How are you determining that "the assignment to a is not working properly"?  Also, what is `MY_String`?

Comment: Your code is very opaque. We have no idea what `func` does or what `MY_String` is, what the `replace` method actually does, what the cast operator does, etc. Also if `My_String` manages it's own memory, you're returning a pointer to a `delete[]`ed block of memory.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth That is because, I can run it in the debugger, and stop at 'return a' and see a has garbage.. But after reading the comments, I feel the assignment is working, but going out of scope after the if block

Answer (score 7):

I have no idea what `MY_String` is.  But whatever it is, it's a local variable.  So it goes out of scope at the end of the `if` block.  So whatever its `operator const char*` does, it's probably not going to give you sensible results once the underlying object is destroyed.

The only way this could possibly work is if the overloaded operator dynamically allocated a new `char` buffer, and returned a pointer to it.  But that would be absurd.

Comment: So your reply makes sense, how do I avoid this but? MY_String is a string class. The only reason I am using it is to use the replace function. I can either not use that class and manually do a search and replace on a.

Comment: @tryurbest: one possible fix is to return `std::string` or `MY_String` from `my_func1` instead of `const char*`. Another is to use `strdup((const char*)b)` or similar to get a copy of the string data to return, and make sure the caller frees it (which means when you return `a` unchanged you'll have to copy that too). Another is to have the caller pass in another parameter, a pointer to a writable buffer long enough to contain the result data (if that's predictable). You copy the string data into that instead of returning a pointer. By far the easiest is to return `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to tell without seeing the actual interface for `MY_String` but I will assume its behavior by your comments.

It looks like your assigning to `a` the buffer allocated in `b`. But `b` is disallocated at the end of the if-block. So `b` is destroyed and so his buffer (I think).

That would explain why your `a` points to garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can assign to `a` even if it's NULL. What you can't do is assign to `*a`.

Does `b` use automatic storage for its members? If so, make sure you're not returning a pointer to one of those from the conversion operator, since it will become invalid once `b` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `b` is no longer in scope outside the `if` block. To fix it, you'll need to allocate some memory for `a` first (using `new`). This  isn't very C++ like, though, and you could easily cause a memory leak and blow your whole leg off.